# How to remove a scheduled toast notification

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I knew how to do scheduled toast notification
from this sample 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Schedules-Toast-notificatio-457e599b#content

but now what I want to do is knowing how to remove the toast that has been created 
I tried this code but it's not working

```
IReadOnlyList<ScheduledToastNotification> scheduled =
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().GetScheduledToastNotifications();

foreach (ScheduledToastNotification notify in scheduled)
{
    if (notify.Id == id)
    {
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().RemoveFromSchedule(notify);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works. Are you setting the notification ID when you create it? You need to set it and keep a list of the created notification's IDs to be able to cancel it later.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove scheduled tile notifications by using the Clear method. 
See detail at [How to reset the TileUpdateManager from all scheduled tile notifications?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/039f8e80-6590-42e6-954b-8407ff382d0f)

Comment: I don't want to clear all the toasts .. here every toast has an ID after calling function .GetScheduledToastNotifications() I know in the debug that it returns an empty toast .. btw thanks :)

Comment: so what are you seeing?  the Id is empty/null Or the id matches yet the call to RemoveFromSchedule doesn't seem to work (because presumably u see the toast show up later)?

Comment: yes the ID was empty .. I'm sorry, I realized now what's wrong in my code and this function is correct and works now :).. thanks and sorry

Comment: So are you going to update your question or specify what was wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.removefromschedule), the problem is that you're creating more than one toast notifier. Instead, you should use the same toast notifier to remove your scheduled notifications.